# React countdown timer to run only on EST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using `react-countdown-timer` to display a counter in my React app. I want the timer to always use EST to compare as current time even if the page is loaded in any other time-zone.

In the documentation, I do see that it accepts a custom `now()` handler to which I can pass my time to. I used `Moment-timezone` to convert the current timezone in EST but the problem is that the `now()` handler for `react-countdown-timer` only takes time in `Date.now()` function's format which is the same in whichever timezone.

How can I implement this use case? I think there are 2 ways:

1. To convert Moment() time in EST and then convert it into appropriate
   milliseconds
2. To make react-countdown-timer accept other formats of data for it's now() handler.

How can this be implemented? 
Current code:

```
<Text mx={2} bold color='white'>Only LEFT <Countdown date={expire} now={() => {
    let z = Moment().tz('America/New_York').format('x')
    return z
}} />
```